# completely show/hide tabbar controller and use the space

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to hide the tabbar controller and display uiimageview similar to how it is done in native photo library of iphone. I have already created the library but I am having problem in displaying the images on next view by hiding tabbar. I am able to hide the tabbar but when I try to add the uiimageview it does not expend to space taken up by tab bar. I want my uiimageview to stretch till bottom of the screen. 
I even want to add a button on that empty space but I am not able to do it.

My code to hide tab bar:

```
 self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
```

Can some one please help me?

Thanks
Pankaj

Comment: do u got any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
```

and

```
 [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
```

Comment: I have already tried that multiple times but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

just use below two methods to hide or show tabbar controller. put this methods in delegate class so it's easy to call from any class.

```
- (void) hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller {

int height = 480;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews) {
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]) {
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, height, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
    } 
    else {
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x,view.frame.origin.y, 320, 436)];
    }
}
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

```
- (void) showTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller {

    int height = 480;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3]; 

    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews) {

        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]) {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, height, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];            
        } 
        else {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, height)];
        }
    }    

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Should you hard code height, considering different form factors ? Maybe 'int height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;' ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the frame of the bottom subview of the `tabBarController`'s view property, like so:

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
UIView* subview = (UIView*)[self.tabBarController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
imageView.frame = subview.frame = self.window.bounds;
```

This is something I've used in some form in a couple of in-production products. Whether or not you actually want to utilize `self.window.bounds` depends on if your current class has a window property pointing to the mainWindow instance of `UIWindow`, whether you are supporting multiple orientations (bounds of window stays the same regardless of the current `UIInterfaceOrientation`, view controllers rotate, windows do not) and if you need to account for the status bar. If accounting for the status bar (`UIStatusBar`), offset the y & height by 20. Casting subview to UIView allows you to use dot syntax in this case (the static analyzer can't tell which objects are in an array).

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggled on that for hours. Finally I found a solution. Just follow the following steps:

- Tick the box *Hide Bottom Bar on Push* in your child view controller (the one you want to hide the tab bar) from Storyboard.
- Add the following code in the `viewWillAppear` method in your root view controller: `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = false`.
- Add the following code in the `viewWillAppear` method in your pushed view controller: `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true`.

That's all. It just works!